# How can migration files be compatible with a git revert command, given that reverting a commit that includes a migration file would make it disappear?

Tags: git, migration, pipeline, database-migration, git-revert

I believe the question is self-explanatory, but I would like to add some details and clarifications.

Suppose I have a commit that includes a migration file, and after the commit is pushed to the pipelines in CI/CD, the 'up' command of the migration is run. Now, I want to revert that commit. How can I run the 'down' migration? It's worth noting that the migration file would disappear with the commit revert.

One solution I have considered is to run the 'down' command of the specific migration to undo it before reverting the commit itself. However, I would prefer to restrict manual runs of such commands and execute them only from pipelines in CI/CD.

Considering this constraint, the only solution I can think of is to revert the entire commit, including the migration file, and create a new migration file that undoes the changes made by the original migration. However, in this case, the original migration would still appear in the list of migrations, as it was not actually rolled back by the 'down' or 'undo' command.

Taking into account the above constraints, what are your suggestions? I did not specify the exact language/framework/packages used because the problem is not dependent on them.

What I am expecting is for the changes made by the original migration file to be reverted along with the commit itself, while maintaining an elegant solution that preferably runs the migration files only from pipelines and not manually from consoles.

Comment: Have any ideas about your question?